# why my nested cursor displays twice the results?

Tags: mysql, nested, cursors

I am using nested cursors to retrieve the last hour of work for many different persons.
For that, I first take the ids of each person in the first cursor, and send the ids to the second cursor which select a max(hour) for each person's id. The returned values are correct, but the displayed results are duplicated, unless when I test the first cursor alone, it displays only one result for each id.
Maybe the answer is easy to see, but I don't after doing many attempts to solve it. Thanks for your help.
Here is my code :

BLOCK1:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE no_more_rows INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE v_idChauffeur VARCHAR(7);

    DECLARE c_idChauffeur CURSOR FOR
        SELECT DISTINCT id_chauffeur FROM temp 
        RIGHT JOIN chauffeur 
        ON temp.logon = chauffeur.matricule_chauffeur
        WHERE logon IN (SELECT matricule_chauffeur from chauffeur)
        order by id_chauffeur;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET no_more_rows = TRUE;

    OPEN c_idChauffeur;
        get_idChauffeur:LOOP
            FETCH c_idChauffeur INTO v_idChauffeur;
            IF no_more_rows THEN CLOSE c_idChauffeur;
            LEAVE get_idChauffeur;
            END IF;
```

BLOCK2:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE no_more_rows2 INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE v_maxHeure VARCHAR(20);

DECLARE c_maxHeure CURSOR FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT(max(heure)) as heure from temp
    right join chauffeur ON temp.logon = chauffeur.matricule_chauffeur
    where id_chauffeur = v_idChauffeur
    order by heure;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET no_more_rows2 = TRUE;

OPEN c_maxHeure;
    get_maxHeure:LOOP
        FETCH c_maxHeure INTO v_maxHeure;
        SELECT v_maxHeure,v_idChauffeur;
        IF no_more_rows2 THEN CLOSE c_maxHeure;
        LEAVE get_maxHeure;
        END IF;
    END LOOP get_maxHeure;
    END BLOCK2;
END LOOP get_idChauffeur;
END BLOCK1
```

And here are some of the duplicated results :

```
v_maxHeure 23:02:17 v_idChauffeur 93
v_maxHeure 23:02:17 v_idChauffeur 93


v_maxHeure 23:24:12 v_idChauffeur 99
v_maxHeure 23:24:12 v_idChauffeur 99

v_maxHeure 15:19:28 v_idChauffeur 100
v_maxHeure 15:19:28 v_idChauffeur 100
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why are you using 2 cursors in the first place, to get data that could be be easily  retrieved with a simple SQL instruction ? This just looks like a competition to come with the most complicated system to achieve a simple task.

Answer (score 0):

The code really seems complicated for a fairly simple db task. 
Based on the assumption from your code, there two tables (temp & chauffeur) that are joined with "temp.logon = chauffeur.matricule_chauffeur". 
Now you wanted to get the distinct records of Max(hour) (i.e. max(temp.heure)) and Person's ID (i.e. id_chauffeur). 
I believe the above task can be achieved with a fairly less complicated query as below.

```html
SELECT DISTINCT(max(temp.heure)) as heure, temp.id_chauffeur
FROM temp INNER JOIN chauffeur ON temp.logon = chauffeur.matricule_chauffeur
ORDER BY temp.heure;
```

(Note: I just compiled the query with a dry run, as I don't have the table structure. Hoping it will work for you... Cheers!)

Comment: Hi,
thanks for your answers.  I had tested the query you suggest, but it doesn't work. Here's what happens :

QUERY :
`SELECT DISTINCT(max(temp.heure)) as heure, (chauffeur.)id_chauffeur
FROM temp (RIGHT JOIN) chauffeur ON temp.logon = chauffeur.matricule_chauffeur
ORDER BY temp.heure LIMIT 0, 30;`

MySQL said that "in aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #2 of 
SELECT list contains non-aggregated column c1kpisteloi_dev.chauffeur.id_chauffeur this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"

That's why I separated this in cursors

Comment: Did you try after adding GROUP BY clause ?
SELECT DISTINCT(max(temp.heure)) as heure, temp.id_chauffeur
FROM temp INNER JOIN chauffeur ON temp.logon = chauffeur.matricule_chauffeur
GROUP BY temp.id_chauffeur
ORDER BY temp.heure;

Comment: Hi, yes I did, but it didn't work. Thanks anyway :D I'm currently at work, so I'll update lately my issue to be more precise

Comment: Unfortunately, I am a bit short of time to achieve this, so I let it for a moment. I finally solve it in php - without the duplications. But be sure ... I'll be back when I find the reason of those duplications.